# Wife of a British citizen living in France with Article 10 residence card, can she visit the UK without a visa

Tags: visas

I am a British citizen living in France.  My wife has an (Article 10) residence card.

Can she tavel to the UK with me without a visa?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as long as you travel before the end of 2020.  See [Entering the UK as the holder of an Article 10 or 20 residence card](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card) for more information.

As things stand now, if you travel after the end of 2020, and if your wife's nationality is a "visa nationality," she will need a visa, though there is a small chance that the negotiations taking place during the transition period will change that.